# Share POSIX message queue between users in the same group

Tags: c, linux, posix, share, message-queue

I'm trying to open and create a POSIX message queue with one user (named "usuario-prueba") in order to send a message to the queue, and just open and receive the message with another user (named "usuario-prueba2"). Both users belong to the same group, however it seems impossible to open the queue with the second user (I get "permission denied" message).

Here're some outputs:

```
usuario-prueba@myhost:~$ id
uid=1001(usuario-prueba) gid=1002(usuario-prueba) grupos=1002(usuario-prueba),1001(pruebas-mqueue)

usuario-prueba2@myhost:~$ id
uid=1002(usuario-prueba2) gid=1003(usuario-prueba2) grupos=1003(usuario-prueba2),1001(pruebas-mqueue)
```

As you can see both users belong to the same group (pruebas-mqueue) as I told before.

I'm creating and opening the queue with:

```
flags = O_RDWR | O_CREAT
mode  = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What group's the message queue in, 1001(pruebas-mqueue)?  Did you do something like newgroup, to make that active?  If the shared group is newly created is it active, do you need to relog a user?

Comment: It seems that if I change sending user's gid to the same as "pruebas-mqueue" (the shared group) it works. I thought that it would be enough to belong to the group, but it also has to have the same gid. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Well with files, you have ways of setting them to the group, with BSD semantics or s+g inherited from directory (which is very convenient).  I don't know whether the directories in /dev/mqueue under Linux, represent the group info, and if chgrp operation would work for deciding access.  Really it's a shame that UNIX didn't stick to "everything's a file" when implementing SysV shared memory, or BSD TCP/IP networking.  Linux's direction is to make more things files, with these special system filesystems.

Comment: Hi again Rob. I have tried changing the queue's file permission (the files mounted with mount -t mqueue) giving it writing access and it actually works too. I don't know why is the information about this subject so obfuscated, but I have finally come to a solution. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Cool!  The "everything is a file" concept is very powerful and general, I've never touched mqueues, but I could guess what the solutions to the problem were, from analagous situations.  Sometimes, it's hard to think of something simple, like file perms on a mqueue.  I'm not really sure if it's "obfuscated", I guessed because I know through reading interviews/discussions Linus's philosophy.  I saw there were files by reading the man page - http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview